# Execution failed for task ':camera:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, flutter, camera

I have created a new Flutter project and added the [`camera`](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin. After adding that dependency I got many errors. I used Flutter version is *2.5.2* and *minSdkVersion 21*.

In the *pubspec.yaml* file,

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  camera: ^0.9.4+4
```

Errors are as follows,

```
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\Camera.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
import android.media.EncoderProfiles;
                    ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: package android.media
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\Camera.java:935: error: cannot find symbol
  EncoderProfiles getRecordingProfile() {
  ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: class Camera
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import android.media.EncoderProfiles;
                    ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: package android.media
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  private EncoderProfiles recordingProfile;
          ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: class ResolutionFeature
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
  public EncoderProfiles getRecordingProfile() {
         ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: class ResolutionFeature
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:187: error: cannot find symbol
  public static EncoderProfiles getBestAvailableCamcorderProfileForResolutionPreset(
                ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: class ResolutionFeature
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\media\MediaRecorderBuilder.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
import android.media.EncoderProfiles;
                    ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: package android.media
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\media\MediaRecorderBuilder.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
  private final EncoderProfiles encoderProfiles;
                ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: class MediaRecorderBuilder
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\media\MediaRecorderBuilder.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
      @NonNull EncoderProfiles encoderProfiles, @NonNull String outputFilePath) {
               ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: class MediaRecorderBuilder
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\media\MediaRecorderBuilder.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
      @NonNull EncoderProfiles encoderProfiles,
               ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: class MediaRecorderBuilder
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:186: error: cannot find symbol
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                                ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\Camera.java:208: error: reference to MediaRecorderBuilder is ambiguous
      mediaRecorderBuilder = new MediaRecorderBuilder(getRecordingProfileLegacy(), outputFilePath);
                             ^
  both constructor MediaRecorderBuilder(CamcorderProfile,String) in MediaRecorderBuilder and constructor MediaRecorderBuilder(EncoderProfiles,String) in MediaRecorderBuilder match
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:118: error: cannot find symbol
      EncoderProfiles profile =
      ^
  symbol:   class EncoderProfiles
  location: class ResolutionFeature
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:120: error: package EncoderProfiles does not exist
      List<EncoderProfiles.VideoProfile> videoProfiles = profile.getVideoProfiles();
                          ^
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:121: error: package EncoderProfiles does not exist
      EncoderProfiles.VideoProfile defaultVideoProfile = videoProfiles.get(0);
                     ^
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:200: error: cannot find symbol
          return CamcorderProfile.getAll(cameraIdString, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getAll(String,int)
  location: class CamcorderProfile
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:204: error: cannot find symbol
          return CamcorderProfile.getAll(cameraIdString, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_2160P);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getAll(String,int)
  location: class CamcorderProfile
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:208: error: cannot find symbol
          return CamcorderProfile.getAll(cameraIdString, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getAll(String,int)
  location: class CamcorderProfile
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:212: error: cannot find symbol
          return CamcorderProfile.getAll(cameraIdString, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getAll(String,int)
  location: class CamcorderProfile
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:216: error: cannot find symbol
          return CamcorderProfile.getAll(cameraIdString, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getAll(String,int)
  location: class CamcorderProfile
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:220: error: cannot find symbol
          return CamcorderProfile.getAll(cameraIdString, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_QVGA);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getAll(String,int)
  location: class CamcorderProfile
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:224: error: cannot find symbol
          return CamcorderProfile.getAll(cameraIdString, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
                                 ^
  symbol:   method getAll(String,int)
  location: class CamcorderProfile
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:241: error: package EncoderProfiles does not exist
      List<EncoderProfiles.VideoProfile> videoProfiles = recordingProfile.getVideoProfiles();
                          ^
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:243: error: package EncoderProfiles does not exist
      EncoderProfiles.VideoProfile defaultVideoProfile = videoProfiles.get(0);
                     ^
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\media\MediaRecorderBuilder.java:32: error: reference to MediaRecorderBuilder is ambiguous
    this(camcorderProfile, outputFilePath, new MediaRecorderFactory());
    ^
  both constructor MediaRecorderBuilder(CamcorderProfile,String,MediaRecorderFactory) in MediaRecorderBuilder and constructor MediaRecorderBuilder(EncoderProfiles,String,MediaRecorderFactory) in MediaRecorderBuilder match
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\media\MediaRecorderBuilder.java:79: error: package EncoderProfiles does not exist
      EncoderProfiles.VideoProfile videoProfile = encoderProfiles.getVideoProfiles().get(0);
                     ^
C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\media\MediaRecorderBuilder.java:80: error: package EncoderProfiles does not exist
      EncoderProfiles.AudioProfile audioProfile = encoderProfiles.getAudioProfiles().get(0);
                     ^
27 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':camera:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried clearing the cache, but this issue occurs as the same.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try updating your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 31.

Comment: Thanks, Dinithi, It's running when set up as you mentioned. but now having some warnings like these `` C:\Users\Lakshan\Documents\SDKs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\camera-0.9.4+4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\camera\features\resolution\ResolutionFeature.java:154: warning: [deprecation] get(int,int) in CamcorderProfile has been deprecated
          return CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH); `` 
totally 7 warnings there. but it's better than previous error. Haha. Thanks

Comment: Yes this working fix do not try to flutter pub cache repair  cos it  reinstall flutter at all

Comment: Can you more explain ? Why version 31 ? What is the issue exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: I also tried with that way. but it was not fixed. :(

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue after spending a day came to conclusion we need to upgraded our Flutter version.

```
flutter upgrade
```

Or

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `compileSdkVersion` to 31. Because I got some more errors when I changed `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: That's what [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70000547/3025856) already suggests. Or are you suggesting that setting the `targetSdkVersion` isn't necessary or desirable? If so, you should [edit] your answer to explain that, if only to help future readers understand why your answer is different from the accepted answer.

Comment: because when i changed targetSdkVersion i get some more errors so change only compileSdkVersion...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 31.
And if that doesn't work, change your *pubspec.yaml* file and add this:

```
camera:
 git:
  url: https://github.com/flutter/plugins
  path: packages/camera/camera
  ref: 9e46048ad2e1f085c1e8f6c77391fa52025e681f
```

You can check the fix at *[[camera] Fix CamcorderProfile Usages #4423](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/4423)*.